# Obiee - Rank Function of Date fields

Tags: oracle, obiee

I need to rank the start date of the Job first (Desc) to get the current job title and the next job title.

Start Date  End Date    Job Title
2/16/2013   12/5/2014   associate1
1/1/2015    2/5/2015    assistant
5/6/2015                    driver

Basically, I need a column called Rank

Start Date  End Date    Job Title    Rank
2/16/2013   12/5/2014   associate1    3 
1/1/2015    2/5/2015    assistant     2
5/6/2015                    driver        1

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions. Didn't none of these answers help you?

Comment: on the current one above, I have not received any answers.

Comment: On the past, I apologized- I was not able to follow up. Still waiting on the above

Comment: Your format is broken, The data should be displayed as code (fixed font). If you edit your queszion you van see a question mark in the upper corner. This will display some icons that will help to format text. It also will display a link to an advanced help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start Date  End Date    Current Job Question    Job Title   Current Job
2/16/2014   12/5/2015   No                      associate1  Intern
11/1/2013   2/5/2014    No                      associat2
12/12/2015  1/11/2016   No                      associate3
4/3/2016                Yes                                 Intern
```

Is this supposed to be your data set? If yes what do you want to get out?

Your pseudo code doesn't make any sense:
Case WHEN "Current Job Question" = Yes or "End Date" is Null Then Current

"Then Current"...then current what? "Then 'Current'" the string result? Your "Yes" in the pseudo code also isn't a string so I guess you just wrote something and not actual code.

Also: no END...

Comment: Thanks for the comments- I modified the data above

Comment: If you keep changing the original question you'll never get a useful answer